# Is there any way to find K-nearest neighbors allocation free?

Tags: julia, knn

I need this for a simulation study.

MWE:

```
x = rand(10,4)
y = rand(5,4)
```

For each row in y I want to find index of its 5-nn in x, i.e. result should be a 5by5 matrix of index.

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example? KNN is a predictive algorithm. If you would like to predict the classes of `y` in `x`, the result should be 5x1. And you have not labels. I don't get it.

Comment: I just need the first 5-nn I don't need prediction, e.g. for `y[1,:]` there should be 5 rows in `x` which are closest (euclidean distance) to it.

Comment: `y[1,:]` has 5-nn, `y[2,:]` has 5-nn, etc thus 5 by 5

Comment: I played around with some optimizations here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/272777/180160. That's already usable, but maybe some more improvements arrive (although there's very few Julia users on Code Review).

Answer (score 3):

It turns out this is incomplete, but I'll post my attempt nevertheless.

"Reinterpreting" a matrix into a vector of vectors without allocation is conceptually simple, but requires implementing a new array type. Such a type is provided by [JuliennedArrays.jl](https://github.com/bramtayl/JuliennedArrays.jl)'s `Sliced`.

The simplest implementation IHMO is this one:

```
mapslices(y, dims=2) do row
    partialsortperm(Slices(x, 2), 1:5, by=x -> norm(x - row))
end
```

Which still allocates something; this must at least be the indexing vector used by `partialsortperm` and the intermediate rows.

I tried to get rid of that in this function:

```
function knnslice!(result, x, y, k)
    result_sliced = Slices(result, 2)
    x_sliced = Slices(x, 2)
    y_sliced = Slices(y, 2)
    indices = collect(axes(x, 1))
    for i in eachindex(result_sliced, y_sliced)
        result_sliced[i] .= partialsortperm!(indices, x_sliced, 1:k, by=x -> norm(x - y_sliced[i]))
    end
    return result
end
knnslice(x, y, k) = knnslice!(similar(x, Int, size(y, 1), k), x, y, k)
```

But the results are hardly an improvement, at least when compared on arrays of the size of your example data.  I'm not sure how this can be brought down any more with this kind of implementation.

The missing piece would be a sortperm implementation which directly works on slices.  For small `k`, this should be doable with one iteration over x and maintaining the results row as buffer (or even small heap) of that size instead of performing a partial sort.  Something like:

```
function knnslice!(result, x, y, k)
    for (i_r, i_y) in zip(axes(result, 1), axes(y, 1))
        result_row = @view(result[i_r, :])
        fill!(result_row, 1)
        f(r) = norm(@view(x[r, :]) - @view(y[i_y, :]))
        for j_x in axes(x, 1)
            heappush!(result_row, j_x; by=f)
        end
    end
    return result
end
```

where `heappush!` should be insertion into a bounded minimum heap with order `by` (something like what [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) in Python provides, but keeping the size of the queue fixed).

Comment: You can just use ` collect(eachrow(m))` which will also allocate references to rows but no data gets copied

Comment: Yeah, but since the problem seems to scale with `x` I wanted to avoid that.